# conflicting types for 'outchar'

Tags: c

I am a newbie to C programming. I'm learning by reading the chapters and doing the examples from the book "Teach Yourself C" by Herbert Schildt. I'm trying to run this program in Dev C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    outchar('A');
    outchar('B');
    outchar('C');
}

outchar(char ch)
{
    printf("%c", ch);
}
```

but I get this error when I compile it:

```
20  1   C:\Dev-Cpp\main.c   [Error] conflicting types for 'outchar'

21  1   C:\Dev-Cpp\main.c   [Note] an argument type that has a default 
promotion can't match an empty parameter name list declaration

15  2   C:\Dev-Cpp\main.c   [Note] previous implicit declaration of 'outchar' was here
```

Please help me with this!

Comment: Unfortunately, the book you're mentioning came out in June 1997 (that was the 3rd edition, yours might even be older). C has evolved quite a bit since then - lots of "margin cases" which were allowed in early C aren't anymore. Better get a recent book. That one will only frustrate you, with examples that don't work anymore, and if you're just learning, you won't be able to understand many of the reasons *why* things need to be done differently either.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you haven't *declared* `outchar` before you use it. That means that the compiler will assume it's a function returning an `int` and taking an undefined number of undefined arguments.

You need to add a *prototype* pf the function before you use it:

```
void outchar(char);  /* Prototype (declaration) of a function to be called */

int main(void)
{
    ...
}

void outchar(char ch)
{
    ...
}
```

Note the declaration of the `main` function differs from your code as well. It's actually a part of the official C specification, it *must* return an `int` and *must* take either a `void` argument or an `int` and a `char**` argument.

Comment: I agree with you needing a prototype, but i disagree with `the compiler will assume it's a function returning an int and taking an undefined number of undefined arguments`. It assumes the argument list in the call, *after autopromotion*, is correct, so it implicitly declares `int outchar(int ch)`.

Answer (score 0):

In C, the order that you define things often matters.  Either move the definition of outchar to the top, or provide a prototype at the top, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void outchar(char ch);

int main()
{
    outchar('A');
    outchar('B');
    outchar('C');
    return 0;
}

void outchar(char ch)
{
    printf("%c", ch);
}
```

Also, you should be specifying the return type of every function.  I added that for you.